# Printf happens twice in while loop?

Tags: c, printf

So I'm a beginner to programming and thought I would try and make a basic calculator that gives the sum or product of two numbers. However, in the `while` loop of this program, the first `printf` seems to print twice after the first iteration of the loop. Any help rectifying this would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int multiply(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}

void printMultiply(int x, int y) {
    int result = multiply(x, y);
    printf("\n%d\n", result);
}

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

void printAdd(int x, int y) {
    int result = add(x, y);
    printf("\n%d\n", result);
}

int main() {
    int product1 = 0;
    int product2 = 0;

    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;

    while (true) {
        // this prints twice after first iteration?
        printf("Would you like to add or multiply? (press a or  m)\n");

        char choice = ' ';
        scanf("%c", &choice);

        if (choice == 'm') {
            printf("What two numbers would you like to multiply? (leave a space between numbers\n");
            scanf("%d%d", &product1, &product2);
            printMultiply(product1, product2);
        } else
        if (choice == 'a') {
            printf("What two numbers would you like to add?  (leave a space between numbers\n");

            scanf("%d%d", &sum1, &sum2);
            printAdd(sum1, sum2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably hit the linefeed from the scanf, since it doesn't fall in your known choices it loops.

Comment: `scanf(...)` is reacting to an unseen return character.  Try putting a space character in front of the format string to consume the `return` (_newline_) character: `scanf(" %c", &choice);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the first iteration, you're seeing a newline (`\n`) in your first call to `scanf`.

All you need to do is use a leading space in your format string to eat up any whitespace:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

Comment: That is strange for me to understand. I had this working using std::cin with no problems, which is what threw me. So pressing 'enter' after the two numbers means scanf automatically reads \n the next time round?

Comment: Yes. You need to consume the newline character somewhere. It's a common gotcha with `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

'\n' is entered to ch after 1st iteration.
remove it from buffer.

scanf("%d%d", &sum1, &sum2);

scanf("%c", &enter);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scanf("\n%c", &choice);
```

This will sort out your problem.